# How can I get date range using dayjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dayjs

I want to tell ***if a random day is in 7 days from now on***. I know there is `isBetween` function, but I want to solve this problem only using `diff`. when I run the code below, this error occurred.

```
Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'number'.(2365)
```

Here is my code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const randomDay = dayjs('2022-09-15');
  const today = dayjs('2022-09-12');
  return (
    <div>{ 0 < randomDay.diff(today, 'day') < 7 && <h1>Today is later</h1>}</div>
  );
}
```

What is the problem? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do two comparisions at once.

```
const diff = randomDay.diff(today, 'day');
```

...

```
0 <  diff && diff < 7
```

Comment: Thanks!! I I resolved that problem with this solution!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the second argument in **diff** function.

```
const dayJS = require('dayjs')

const randomDay = dayJS('2022-09-15')
const today = dayJS('2022-09-12')

const difference = randomDay.diff(today, 'days')

console.log(difference) // 3 days

console.log(difference > 7 ? 'After Seven days' : 'Less than 7 days')
```